# Compactness embedding in the periodic Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, periodic-functions, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s>0$ non-integer. Consider the *Sobolev space* given by
$$
H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{ f \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\; ; \; \|f\|_{H^s}<\infty\}
$$
where
$$
\|f\|_{H^s}=\|(1+|x|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}, f \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n),
$$
$\mathcal{F}$ is Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{S}$ is the Schwartz space. Now, given $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open we define
$$
H^s(U)=\{ f \in L^2(U)\; ; \exists \; g \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n), g(x)=f(x),\; \forall\; x \in U\}
$$
with norm
$$
\|f\|_{H^s(U)}= \inf_{g_{|U}=f \atop g \in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)} \|g\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}, f \in H^s(U).
$$

I seen in a doctorate thesis (without proof) the following result:

**Theorem.** If $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain and $s>0$ is such that
$$
s>n\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{q}\right), q\geq 2
$$
then the embedding $H^s(U) \hookrightarrow L^q(U)$ is compact.

**Question.** If $U=\frac{\mathbb{R}^n}{2\pi \mathbb{Z}}$ is the torus then the theorem above holds? Roughly speaking, the theorem above holds in periodic context?

The best result that I found is the Rellich's Theorem in page $73$ of $[1]$. But this theorem don't answer my question (see the theorem in $[1]$, please). Other references are welcome.

$[1]$ J. Roe. [Elliptic Operators, Topology and Asymptotic Methods](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/roeindex.pdf), Pitman Res.Notes in Math Series 179, Longman Scientific and Technical, Harlow, 1988.

Comment: The definition of the norm $\|\cdot\|_{H^{s}}$ is wrong. The definition you gave is for $s \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @VictorHugo You are right. I fixed, I now believe to be right. In this case I think that the space $H^s$ is also called *Slobodeckij space*.

Comment: I don't have a reference right now, but the best answer I can give is: Probably yes, since these estimates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are proven using the Fourier Transform. And in the torus, you have an analogous definition of Fourier Transform.

Comment: @VictorHugo I agree. Do you have a reference of the theorem above mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that if $s>n\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{q}\right)$, then $H^s(\mathbb{T}^n)\hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb{T}^n)$.

The case $q=\infty$ is a consequence of the Sobolev embedding: Indeed in case $s>n/2$, we have $H^s\hookrightarrow C^\alpha$, for an appropriate $\alpha>0$, and this last space embeds compactly into $L^\infty$ by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Therefore we only need to worry about $q<\infty$.  By the same argument as above, and the fact that $L^\infty\hookrightarrow L^q$, we may as well assume that $s< n/2$.

Now notice that
$$
|1-e^{inh}|\lesssim_{a} |nh|^a, \qquad h\in \mathbb{R},
$$
for all $0<a\leq 1$. Using this we can estimate the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)-f(x+h)=:g(x)$ as
$$
|\hat{g}(n)|^2 \lesssim_a |nh|^{2a}|\hat{f}(n)|^2=|h|^{2a} |n|^{2(a-s)}|n|^{2s}|\hat{f}(n)|^2, \qquad n\neq 0.
$$
In order to be able to sum this and get the $H^s$ norm of $f$ on the right, we need $a-s\leq 0$ or $a\leq s$ which can always be arranged. With such a choice we obtain
$$
\| f-f(\cdot +h)\|_{L^2} \lesssim |h|^a \| f\|_{H^s},
$$
which gives equicontinuity in the $L^2$ norm of the unit ball of $H^s$, and so the embedding is compact in the case $q=2$.

For the general case we interpolate: By the Sobolev embedding, if $s>n(1/2-1/q)$ (and without loss of generality $s<n/2$), then there exists $r>q$ such that $H^s\hookrightarrow L^r$ and
$$
\| f\|_{L^r}\lesssim \| f\|_{H^s}.
$$
Therefore, for $b$ satisfying $1/q=b/2+(1-b)/r$ we have
$$
\| g\|_{L^q}\lesssim \| g\|_{L^2}^b\| g\|_{L^r}^{1-b}\lesssim |h|^{ab}\| f\|_{H^s},
$$
using that $\| g\|_{H^s}\leq 2\| f\|_{H^s}$. This proves the compactness of the embedding.

Comment: So, if $n=1$ and $q=4$ we can conclude that $H^s \hookrightarrow L^4$? I not sure, because you assume that $s<n/2=1/2$ and in the $q=4$ we have $s>1/2$.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: See the third paragraph (also what value of $s$ are you using?), let's say $s=1$, $q=4$, then we have $H^1\hookrightarrow L^\infty\hookrightarrow L^4$.

Comment: My question, more precisely is, from your construction, for every $s>1/4$ we have the compact embedding $H^s \hookrightarrow L^4$?I am not fixing values for $s>0$, but only fixing $q=4$ and $n=1$ and so $s>n\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{q}\right)=\frac{1}{4}$. By it's argument, it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: If $1/4<s<1/2$, then the argument goes as I mentioned. If $s=1/2$ you have $H^{1/2}\hookrightarrow H^t \hookrightarrow L^4$ for any $1/4<t<1/2$. If $s>1/2$, then you do as in my previous comment (or as in the case of $s=1/2$, either way works).

Comment: In other words, if $s>1/2$ then  $H^s\hookrightarrow L^\infty\hookrightarrow L^4$ is compact? Even $s>n\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{q}\right)$ not being satisfied?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno: Yes to your first question, since the first embedding is compact. For your second question notice that in dimension $n=1$ you would have $s>1/2>(1/2-1/q)$ for any $q>0$.